# Javascript - Video script issue

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm using this script to play video. But it showing an error like "ReferenceError: videojs is not defined". I couldn't fix this. Can guys help me with this? I have added the script for more clarification. Thanks :)

```
videojs.autoSetup();
    videojs('my_video_1').ready(function(){
      console.log(this.options()); //log all of the default videojs options

       // Store the video object
      var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
      // Make up an aspect ratio
      var aspectRatio = 264/640; 

      function resizeVideoJS(){
        var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
        myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );

      }

      // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
      resizeVideoJS();
      // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
      window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; 
    });
```

Comment: How are you importing videojs?

Comment: You need to embed the script that provides this object to begin with … https://videojs.com/getting-started/

Comment: yes ...videojs is not defined. please check `video.js` file included your project.Check your console.log